# sfdx jwt:grant unable to authenticate

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm having issues trying to use jwt:grant to log in while specifying the instanceurl in the command.  I'm currently working on this in a sandbox.  But our orgs are configured to not allow log ins from login.salesforce and test.saleforce.

When I try this command

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -u myusername@here.com.sandbox -f ~/Documents/JWT/server.key -i [The client Id] -r https://my-custom-domain.cs14.my.salesforce.com
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR:  This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - audience is invalid   
username: sfdcautomation@coverity.com.cicdtest,
clientId: [The client id], 
loginUrl: <Not Specified>, 
privateKey: [correct location]/server.key. 

Try this: Verify the OAuth configuration for this org. For JWT: 
Ensure the private key is correct and the cert associated with the connected app has not expired. 
Ensure the following OAuth scopes are configured [api, refresh_token, offline_access]. 
Ensure the username is assigned to a profile or perm set associated with the connected app. 
Ensure the connected app is configured to pre-authorize admins.
```

But if I disable the login policy and change the instance url to https://test.salesforce.com.  It works.

Any ideas how to solve this?  I won't be able to turn the login policy off in out full sandboxes or production.

Comment: Were you able to progress?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:
[This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - audience is invalid](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252008/this-org-appears-to-have-a-problem-with-its-oauth-configuration-reason-invalid)

Run the following command first

`export SFDX_AUDIENCE_URL=https://test.salesforce.com`