# This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - audience is invalid

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, jwt, force-cli

Error while trying to authorize an org through JWT from SFDX CLI on Windows.

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid <myclientid> --jwtkeyfile server.key --instanceurl https://mysandbox.my.salesforce.com --username <myusername> --setalias PraveenDevJWT
```

I am trying using the above mentioned SFDX CLI command. I have made sure that the user I am using is assigned to the Profile to which the connected app is assigned to.

Here is the error that I see:

> ERROR:  This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - audience is invalid
>
> username: myusername,
>
> clientId: myclientid,
>
> loginUrl: 'Not Specified'
>
> privateKey: server.key.
>
> Try this:
>
> Verify the OAuth configuration for this org. For JWT:
>
> Ensure the private key is correct and the cert associated with the connected app has not expired.
>
> Ensure the following OAuth scopes are configured [api, refresh_token, offline_access].
>
> Ensure the username is assigned to a profile or perm set associated with the connected app.
>
> Ensure the connected app is configured to pre-authorize admins.

The error message says **loginUrl:**  which I reckon can be the issue, but I am not sure how to set it (if it is really required).
Can anyone please help with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Run the following command first

```
export SFDX_AUDIENCE_URL=https://test.salesforce.com
```

Then run

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid <myclientid> --jwtkeyfile server.key --instanceurl https://mysandbox.my.salesforce.com --username <myusername> --setalias PraveenDevJWT
```

Running the above-mentioned commands, worked for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Praveen Tata.. This worked for me. Any idea why this is required?

Comment: @wesfaith I am not totally sure, but it seems like it points the Audience URL to the https://test.salesforce.com which is not by default set.
So, in order to make the CLI know that we want to connect to a sandbox, we need to explicitly tell the Audience URL.

Comment: Seems to be, based on the document below, thank for sharing @PraveenTata: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331188&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1

Answer (score 0):

1- go to "sfdx-project.json" file

2- change "sfdcLoginUrl" from "https://login.salesforce.com" to "https://test.salesforce.com"

3- authorize your org again

It will work