# Unable to authorize Scratch org from cli

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, salesforcedx-cli-auth

I am trying to authorize an scratch org via CLI (`sfdx force:auth:web:login`) with my user which is created by another user and I am not able to authorize it. Getting below error:

```
ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - invalid authorization code 
username: <Not Specified>, 
clientId: PlatformCLI, 
loginUrl: https://login.salesforce.com, 
privateKey: <Not Specified>
Try this:
Verify the OAuth configuration for this org. For JWT:
Ensure the private key is correct and the cert associated with the connected app has not expired.
Ensure the following OAuth scopes are configured [api, refresh_token, offline_access].
Ensure the username is assigned to a profile or perm set associated with the connected app.
```

How can I resolve it? Please help on this.

Comment: What's your Salesforce user profile or licence

Comment: Its system admin only.

Comment: How about trying to execute the first command in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252008/this-org-appears-to-have-a-problem-with-its-oauth-configuration-reason-invalid)?

Comment: The salesforce cli connected app is not available in the scratch org.