# Getting "This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - expired access/refresh token " error in VS Code SFDX

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, salesforcedx-cli-auth

From today, Suddenly, I started getting the below error in VS code whenever I am running any SFDX command:

ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. Reason: invalid_grant - expired access/refresh token
username: 
clientId: PlatformCLI,
loginUrl: https://test.salesforce.com/,
privateKey:

Try this:
Verify the OAuth configuration for this org. For JWT:
Ensure the private key is correct and the cert associated with the connected app has not expired.
Ensure the following OAuth scopes are configured [api, refresh_token, offline_access].
Ensure the username is assigned to a profile or perm set associated with the connected app.
Ensure the connected app is configured to pre-authorize admins.

I thought of Authorizing an org again, but no luck. Also, I gone thru many blogs but still I didn't see any proper solution for this problem.

Can anyone please help in solving this error?

Comment: Are you login to the correct host (https://test.salesforce.com/) when using sfdx force:auth:web:login with the -r flag?

Comment: Yea, I executed sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com command for authorizing but it's been hours and it is still running. Not only with this command, any SFDX command is not working, Getting the above error .

Comment: And the sfdx-project.json file has : {
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://test.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "47.0"
}

Comment: Can you try export SFDX_AUDIENCE_URL=https://test.salesforce.com and then try to authorize your org . Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252008/this-org-appears-to-have-a-problem-with-its-oauth-configuration-reason-invalid

Comment: It shouldn't be running for hours - did it get to open a browser to allow you to authenticate?

Comment: @Swetha, I tried it, it is giving the below error: export SFDX_AUDIENCE_URL=https://test.salesforce.com
export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ export SFDX_AUDIENCE_URL=https://test.salesforce.com
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (export:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @Alba, Yes previously it used to open up in a  browser but suddenly looks like no SFDX command is working

Comment: Then it's definitely related to that. Check this thread please https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/371 and let me know if it helps